# Convert string with modifier to Ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

How to convert string `"/russia/i"` to regular expression `/russia/i`.

I know about `Regexp.new str` and `/#{str}/`, but this does not work in case of modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this solution

```
str = "/russia/i"
re = Regexp.new *str.split('/').slice(1,2)
# => /russia/i
```

Comment: we are on the same page!! :))

Answer (score 4):

If you can trust your input:

```
str = "/russia/i"
re = eval(str) # => /russia/i
```

Comment: +1 This is one of those times that `eval` is a good way to go. I don't normally like it that much, but it's straight-ahead, very clear and maintainable. As always, the caveats about using `eval` with a string the user could have supplied applies.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "/russia/i"
Regexp.new(s[1..s.rindex('/') - 1],s[-1]) # => /russia/i
```

or

```
s = "/russia/i"
s.split("/") # => ["", "russia", "i"]
Regexp.new(s.split("/")[1],1) # => /russia/i
```

or

```
s = "/russia/i"
s.split("/") # => ["", "russia", "i"]
Regexp.new(*s.split("/")[1..-1]) # => /russia/i
```

Comment: Don’t the first two  assume that the modifier is *always* `i` though?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall You are right,but that's the way I reached to the last(better) solution although.Thus didn't delete those. :)